# How to create tile based game in sprite kit with swift?

Tags: ios, macos, swift, sprite-kit

So I'm trying to create a game in sprite kit that is based on the tile system used in games like Pokémon. Since I am relatively new to this language and type of programming, I need some assistance on how to create this grid of tiles and how to make many, many SKSpritenodes with the same (and sometimes different) textures. I have tried creating the grid tile nodes in a method with local variables, but to have multiple of them I would have to call the method 100+ times to generate each tile in a different position adjacent to another. 
How can I go about designing this type of game?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Comment: All the tile game tutorials on that website are for cocos2d not sprite kit alone

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/62049/sprite-kit-tutorial-make-platform-game-like-super-mario-brothers-part-1

Comment: Rather than reinventing the wheel I'd suggest to pick one of the tilemap frameworks that enable you to load and render tilemaps (at least, some include tile picking and other features as well). Orthogonal tilemaps are manageable but still cut into your development time. Iso and hex are non-trivial to implement (correctly).